# SELECT statement for NOT NULL values is returning NULL values.

Tags: php, mysql

I have PHP code that gets values using a `$_POST` and then inserts into a DB. All of the  fields are input based except the `CU00`, etc. because it denotes a primary key .

Now suppose user enters just one row:

```
$ sql="INSERT INTO weekly
VALUES
 ('$_POST[uactual]','$_POST[utarget]','CU001','$a1','$_POST[ucomment]',NOW())
,('$_POST[uactual2]','$_POST[utarget2]','CU002','$a2','$_POST[ucomment2]',NOW())
,('$_POST[uactual3]','$_POST[utarget3]','CU003','$a3','$_POST[ucomment3]',NOW())
,('$_POST[dactual]','$_POST[dtarget]','CD001','$b1','$_POST[dcomment]',NOW())
,('$_POST[dactual2]','$_POST[dtarget2]','CD002','$b2','$_POST[dcomment2]',NOW())
,('$_POST[dactual3]','$_POST[dtarget3]','CD003','$b3','$_POST[dcomment3]',NOW())
,('$_POST[iactual]','$_POST[itarget]','CI001','$c1','$_POST[icomment]',NOW())
,('$_POST[iactual2]','$_POST[itarget2]','CI002','$c2','$_POST[icomment2]',NOW())
,('$_POST[iactual3]','$_POST[itarget3]','CI003','$c3','$_POST[icomment3]',NOW())
,('$_POST[ractual]','$_POST[rtarget]','CR001','$d1','$_POST[rcomment]',NOW())
,('$_POST[ractual2]','$_POST[rtarget2]','CR002','$d2','$_POST[rcomment2]',NOW())
,('$_POST[ractual3]','$_POST[rtarget3]','CR003','$d3','$_POST[rcomment3]',NOW())";
```

SQL TABLE

```
ACTUAL|TARGET|KEY |SIGNAL |TIME 
NULL    NULL  CU001 NULL   00:00
NULL    NULL  CU002 NULL   00:00
NULL    NULL  CU003 NULL   00:00
NULL    NULL  CU004 NULL   00:00
100      200  CU005  300   00:00
```

I want to do a select where only the rows with signal are selected. But when I do a:

```
   SELECT *
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE 
    'signal' IS NOT NULL
```

I get all the rows returned. It is as if there are no NULL values in my table .

Comment: Used a isset ... works wonderfully now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting empty strings into the DB.

Do this:

```
(empty($_POST['uactual']) ? 'NULL' : '\'' . $_POST['uactual'] . '\'')
```

For all `$_POST` variables. Then you can be sure that there will be NULL values.

Please don't do this: `$_POST[uactual]`! PHP will search for defined val first! Do `$_POST['uactual']` Use ' always!

Also, your select is wrong. ` not '. If you don't believe do such query:

```
SELECT 'signal' FROM TABLE
```

This is correct:

```
SELECT `signal` FROM TABLE or
SELECT signal FROM TABLE
```

This will return you string 'signal', not the `signal` column.

```
 WHERE 
    'signal' IS NOT NULL
```

This will always be `true`! This why it returns whole data. You made 2 mistakes then :] In inserting and in selecting data.

Comment: <?php (empty($a1) ? 'NULL' : '\'' . $a1 . '\'')?>

I did this befor inseret bcos this is the signal column but never worked, should I change the SQL now

Comment: No matter where you will do that. Your insert string should contain:
 NULL (without '') or 'somestring' (with '') or 888 (without '' if it should be numbers).
You can also do (int) $x. Then you will be sure that the value will be integer (0 if not numeric string). I would do both (int) + empty :]

Comment: `empty($x) ? NULL : (int) $x` Hope this helps.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function int() <?php (empty($a1) ? 'NULL' : '\'' . int($a1) . '\'')?>

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE signal IS NOT NULL` without '. If you inserted NULLs like you should. In other case `WHERE signal != ''` or `WHERE signal != 0` or even all at once `WHERE signal IS NOT NULL AND signal != '' AND signal != 0`.

Thnx for correcting my answer Lemmings19 :)

Answer (score 3):

```
   SELECT *
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE 
    signal IS NOT NULL
```

`'signal'` is just string literal which is indeed `NOT NULL`.
You possibly meant ` instead of '.

Comment: @SaiVignesh no, `'signal'` is string, not int.

Answer (score 0):

You are not inserting any NULLs. You are inserting empty strings at best.

Also, you should use some validation of your inputs.

Comment: I cannot add comments to below POST, but the answer below is wrong. The quotes around string are not needed, MySQL will not understand that as a string but rather as a column name.

Comment: The problem is that you are not inserting NULLs. You are inserting strings - you need to validate your input and convert empty strings to NULLs where appropriate.

Comment: oh How do I filter empty string then

Comment: when inserting data. I posted the empty() part above.
And there is huge difference between ' and ` in sql! ' is string ` is table!

Comment: <?php (empty($a1) ? 'NULL' : '\'' . $a1 . '\'')?>

I did this befor inseret bcos this is the signal column but never worked, should I change the SQL now